# Sharing database between two projects

Tags: django, heroku

I currently have two different projects in my Heroku folder, their functionality is pretty different, but I need them to share the same database.
Is it possible to share the same database between two different projects in Heroku?

Comment: Sure you just need to set the same DB url in your settings, i dont know if you can run 2 separate django app on the same DB, migrations, auth & session should be a problem

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the reply.